# play a video in a loop with VideoJS library when falling back to Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, video.js

I have experienced problems with using the VideoJS library with older versions of Firefox to display videos. [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com/) provides a fallback to use Flash in this occasion, so that is what I am doing in my code below (`techOrder` uses `flash` first, this is for FF *only*)

```
var golf_vid;

videojs("golf_video", { techOrder: ['flash','html5'] }).ready(function() {
   golf_vid = this;
   golf_vid.on("ended", replay_video);
   golf_vid.play();
});

function replay_video() {
   golf_vid.play();
}
```

The functionality to play the video in a loop works with the `<video>` tag, when i'm not using Flash. But stops and doesn't restart with Flash - is there a way to play it in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this, here it is (hope it helps someone else out in the future).

```
// play the video in a loop and use the correct tech order based on the browser
videojs("golf_video", { loop: true, techOrder: ['flash','html5'] }).ready(function() {
   golf_vid = this;
   golf_vid.on("ended", replay_video);
   golf_vid.play();
});
```